# ValueError message (from sys import argv)

Tags: python

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. I use gedit to write a simple python script which contains

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

for i in argv:
    print(i)
```

Then from terminal (Ubuntu) I try to execute the script which gives error message

> ValueError: Not enough values (expected 4, got 1)

Comment: What's the output if you print `sys.argv`? It seems like the arguments you expect aren't being passed to the script, i.e. `argv` contains only the script name and nothing else.

Comment: I bet your argv is `['']`, and 1 isn't equal to 4

Comment: How did you run the program? That's what matters here. `argv` holds the script name plus arguments. Your error means that you ran the script with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am not doing anything on my own. I found above script here http://forum.codecall.net/topic/76134-help-understanding-from-sys-import-argv/. So, I don't understand why it does not work.

Comment: I use gedit to write the script and then from Konsole (Ubuntu) I execute the script (python name.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script, first, second, third = argv` unpacks 4 values from `argv`. This only works if `argv` has exactly 4 items. `argv` contains the name of the script followed by parameters to the script. So,

```
python3 myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

would work and `script` would hold "myscript.py", `first` would hold "arg1", and etc...

But

```
python3 myscript.py
```

would fail with your error because the 3 expected parameters are not there.